# Is it possible to create Applescript to log in on a website?

Tags: applescript

I am new to applescript and I need some help.

Is it possible to create Apple script, that would paste text (username and password) on a log in page. The problem is, that the site has both fields (username and password) declared as a password field, so no password managing software works (it inputs the password to both fields).

So the script would probably have to first "paste" the username and then somehow "press TAB to get to the next field" and than "paste" the password.

Answer (score 0):

There is no code to start with, but here is an example of a method with Applescript.

```
tell application "Safari"

    activate

    tell application "System Events" to tell process "Safari"

        keystroke "theUsername"
        delay 0.5
        key code 48 -- Tab
        delay 0.5
        keystroke "thePassword"

    end tell

end tell
```